# Using echo to pipe a string with C style comments

Tags: bash, echo

In my bash script I am using echo to pipe a string containing c style comments into the mail command as follows:
`echo -e $EMAIL_TXT | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENT` where `$EMAIL_TXT` contains
`"/* some text */"`. In the email I am getting a list of all directories in the root since it is actually evalutating `/*` as all directories in root. How do I get my script to evaluate this as a string and not the actual command?

Comment: This is a recipe for security nightmares.

Comment: `mail` (at least, the GNU version) allows you to execute arbitrary shell commands by entering a line starting with `~! ` (Or `~: shell `). That works even if stdin is redirected to a file, so if the file contains such a line, the shell command will be executed. The potential security issues should be obvious.

Comment: could you give an example? I'm pretty new to bash.

Comment: an example command? How about `rm -fR /` (Delete all files).

Comment: right, but is there a way someone outside my system could make my system execute this script?

Comment: @azrosen92: That depends on how you create $EMAIL_TXT. If there is some way of including arbitrary text in it, then someone could include the `~! dangerous command` text, and it would get executed by `mail`.

Comment: oh I see, I think that is very unlikely to happen

Comment: @azrosen92: I think everyone who has created a security hole has at some point said "I think that is very unlikely to happen" :) Nonetheless, it happens with depressing regularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around `$EMAIL_TXT`

```
echo "$EMAIL_TXT"
```

A note about `-e`:

`-e` causes escape sequences (such as `\n` and `\t`) in the arguments to `echo` to be converted to their corresponding characters (newline and tab, in those cases). It is not necessary if the arguments contain actual newline and tab characters, and it is probably not desirable either. Suppose, for example, that this answer were the text of the email. In that case, `echo -e` would convert the `\n`'s into newlines, completely destroying the sense of the message.

`bash` does not convert `\n` into a newline, except in one specific case. So if you type:

```
echo "foo\nbar"
```

You'll see

```
foo\nbar
```

Because that is what you typed; `bash` does not convert the escape sequence. However, you can get bash to convert the escape sequence by using a different quotation form:

```
$ echo $'foo\nbar'
foo
bar
$
```

Of course, you can also just include a newline:

```
$ echo "foo
> bar"
foo
bar
$
```

Comment: because there are also newlines in `$EMAIL_TXT`

Comment: @azrosen92: echo works with newlines. Why do you think it doesn't? (I'm curious where this incorrect meme comes from; it seems to show up everywhere.)

Comment: I've been trying echo with newlines and it prints the newline symbol instead of the actual newline

Comment: azrosen92: if you type echo `"foo\nbar"` then it will echo `\n` because that's what you typed. If you type `echo "foo` then type a new line (i.e. enter) then type `bar"`, it will echo the newline just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the variable.  I.e.

```
echo -e "$EMAIL_TXT" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENT
```

Run just the echo command with and without the quotes to see the difference.

Comment: I see in another comment that you're struggling with newlines in your variable.  I've used BASH arrays to overcome limitations with them before.  See this site for a good overview. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/